# Multicraft PHP Leak Memory

Tags: php, memory-leaks, panel, minecraft

I have installed Multicraft 1.8.2 on my server and all is good, but today i look this error :

> [Thu Dec 24 09:45:06.128050 2015] [:error] [pid 11728] [client
>   IP:PORT] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes
>   exhausted (tried to allocate 21228813 bytes) in
>   /var/www/multicraft/protected/yii/web/CBaseCont$

I have no idea for resolve this, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

Answer (score 0):

please increase memory limit in PHP.ini file:

LIKE

```
memory_limit = 512M ;
```